# Select Distinct for First Part of column values, but last part (ticket number) needs to be wildcard

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, archiving

So I have a database of emails sent and received by our ticket system, Cherwell, version 9.3.2. It uses Microsoft SQL as a backend, we're on version 2012. I'm interested in doing cleanup on old or irrelevant emails. For instance emails 3+ years old, or notices sent to technicians saying they have a new task, or notices we send out that really have no value in retaining in full email stored in the database, as Cherwell also creates rows of plaintext for most of these emails.  The table related to mail, TrebuchetMail is this size: 193,883.156 MB. 
I'm wondering if it would improve overall performance to reduce this table, as nearly every type of record in Cherwell would access this table. Granted it would only be those rows relevant to the specific record.

Okay so my question: Subject is a column that stores the subject of the email.  I have a few types of Subjects identified for removal, one example is this:

```
--165765
    select count(*)
    FROM [cherwell].[dbo].[TrebuchetMail]
  where subject like 'You have an unacknowledged Task%';
```

After the `You have an unacknowledged Task` part of the subject is a number, the individual Task object's ID number. So doing a select distinct treats all 165765 rows as distinct, because they are. Can you do a wildcard with select distinct to group together similar but not exactly the same? Is there another function I could use rather than distinct? I realize it actually is distinct, but surely this problem has come up before. "select distinct Subject" query that would group together the rows where Subject is like `'You have an unacknowledged Task%'` and Subject is like `'Ticket #%Created'`. Would I always need some criteria, so maybe this is pointless because I'm going to have to look at the full results to come up with the criteria for the select distinct query anyway.

My goal is to identify different Subjects that could be targeted for archival/removal.

[I found a 2013 thread that was a similar question, but it had to do with dates. The asker wanted to group together rows from a log that grouped together the days, disregarding the time aspect of the log.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwienoS_tJfcAhXQwFkKHQcRANkQFgg3MAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F18530487%2Fselect-distinct-values-using-like&usg=AOvVaw0v-JyCoB_1_AWm7pNeZSTq)  I didn't quite understand how I could translate that to work for my situation.  I'd be very grateful for an explanation if that would work for me.

Comment: What is the actual question here? I am completely lost as to what you need help with.

Comment: I'm with @SeanLange. So you don't actually need distinct even though you say so multiple times? I think? I believe a subquery to return the ID values of the tasks then a count in the outer query would solve this, but it's very unclear. Maybe an example of your data would help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not be the answer you are looking for since it is low tech not based on formula. But since it is most likely a one time action, why not export the database as a table and sort it by the subject field. All the irrelevant records would be grouped together and could be easily deleted.
After this action simply re-import the table to the database. Of course this only works nicely on a flat database, not on a highly linked up one.
At the same time you would have a backup in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to do (bearing in mind I'm not a SQL expert), is create a new subquery/expression that stands in as a new column in your query, as a truncated section of subject.

Something like,

```
Select RecID, (   Subject.Replace('1','').Replace('2','').Replace('3','') As CustomColumn )
From TrebuchetMail
```

and so on, to where you strip out numbers 0-9 anywhere they appear in the subject line.

You can then potentially go distinct based on this I believe.

I'm sure there's a more elegant way of doing this with a Regex expression as well, I just am too novice for it

Not sure how it works out in practice.

Note.... I might have the syntax wrong on those replace commands. I think I'm thinking of how it's done in VB/C# and I think in SQL it's more like Replace(expression, 'text to be replaced', 'text to replace with') but you get the idea